# Testing for unit roots

Tags: hypothesis-testing, stata, unit-root

I am an absolute beginner and I need help on testing for unit-roots in Stata. As the data is unbalanced (no missing values, but some time series begin later than others) it seems to me that I could only use either the Fisher-type unit-root test or the Im-Pesaran-Shin unit-root test. I have 41 panels and data for 10 years. I am wondering which test to use and would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: The command in Stata would be `xtunitroot ips/fisher`. There are many examples in the [pdf documentation](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/xtxtunitroot.pdf). What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. "Only" these two tests relative to what? The literature is huge
2. 10 years sounds very little for a unit root test, be it in the panel or univariate.
3. As to which test to use: if all the series in your panel are stationary an average type test like IPS might be more capable of detecting this, whereas if there are only a few, but strongly, stationary series, the term $-\ln(p_i)$ will contribute a lot to a (possible) rejection of the Fisher statistic. So essentially there is no one single good answer.